# Pause don't works (Unity c#)

Tags: c#, android, ios, unity-game-engine

I writing runner game on Unity (C#) for mobile phones.

I made Pause button on screen, using Canvas - Button.

Also I made code for Pause in Platformer2DUserControl script.

Here it is code of this script:

```
   using UnityEngine;
using UnitySampleAssets.CrossPlatformInput;

namespace UnitySampleAssets._2D
{

    [RequireComponent(typeof(PlatformerCharacter2D))]
    public class Platformer2DUserControl : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private PlatformerCharacter2D character;
        private bool jump;
        public bool paused;

        private void Awake()
        {
            character = GetComponent<PlatformerCharacter2D>();
            paused = false;
        }

        private void Update()
        {

            /*if (Input.GetButton("Fire1"))
            {

            }*/


            if (!jump)
                // Read the jump input in Update so button presses aren't missed.
                 jump = Input.GetButton("Fire1"); //&& CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Jump"); 


        }

        private void FixedUpdate()
        {
            // Read the inputs.
            bool crouch = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl);
            // float h = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal");
            // Pass all parameters to the character control script.
            character.Move(1, false, jump);
            jump = false;

        }
        public void Pause()

        {
            if (!jump)
                // Read the jump input in Update so button presses aren't missed.
                jump = Input.GetButton("Fire1"); //&& CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Jump");

            paused = !paused;


            if (paused)
            {
                jump = !jump;
                Time.timeScale = 0;

            }
            else if (!paused)
            {
               // jump = Input.GetButton("Fire1");
                Time.timeScale = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Pause Button is WORKS well. But when I tap it , my character is jumping and game is pausing.

I want to make that , when I tapping the button game just pausing and character don't jump.

How I can make it. Thank's for help.

Comment: you ***REALLY, HONESTLY, JUST CAN NOT "PAUSE" UNITY GAMES USING THE RIDICULOUS "timescale" TRICK*** Honest to God.  That is, honest to God, just ***NOT*** how they pause games at Nintendo.  It's a really incredibly silly idea someone mentioned in a Unity forum years ago, and it has been copied around on the internet.  it's completely ridiculous.

Comment: "pausing" in game engineering is quite an art form.  for each class of object you have in the scene, you have to *especially write pause code* for that type of thing.  that is *the only way* to implement pause concepts in game engineering.

Comment: Okay, how I can make pause? @JoeBlow

Comment: Or where I can read about this?@JoeBlow

Comment: @JoeBlow: We are here to help others. One of the basic rules here is [Be nice](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice). Ridiculous, silly, ... that's not necessary nor does it help somebody.

Comment: hi Kay - I was saying the *technique* is ridiculous.

Comment: hi @ЕвгенийСухомлин !  you just have to write a pause function, for each thing in the game.  it is a huge amount of work!  if you have a robot, write a pause function. if you have a background, write a pause function, if you have a helicopter, write a pause function.  it is a huge job   :O

Comment: Like you said, that's not how they pause at Nintendo, but this guy is likely just making a small project, not working at Nintendo. Still, it's good to point it out in a nice way.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you not to use the same input for jumping and pausing. Also, separate your jump and pause functionalities into separate functions. For pausing, create a UI button on the screen and make it call a public function on a Pause script, that will toggle pause. Then, in the same function, check if you are paused or not and adjust Time.timescale accordingly

You will have to attach the script with pause functionality on to an object that will always be in a screen (Say, a panel in your canvas or your MainCamera). Under the button, add a new onClick() function after dragging the GO with the apt script to the box. Then, select the public function aforementioned.

```
private bool paused = false;

//The function called by the button OnClick()
public void TogglePause()
{
    paused = !paused;

    if(paused)
        Time.timescale = 0f;
    else
        Time.timescale = 1f;
}
```

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

Well, your code is messed up, but just remove the jump script from the pause method. So it will just pause...

```
public void Pause()

    {
        paused = !paused;

        if (paused)
        {
            Time.timeScale = 0;
        }
        else
        {
           Time.timeScale = 1;
        }
    }
```

Note that Input.GetButton should only be called in Update

**EDIT**

The problem that you have to tap your screen to press the button. And the code jump = Input.GetButton("Fire1"); basically means "Am I tapping the screen?" So both JUMP and PAUSE are triggered.

One solution would be to put a canvas filling the whole screen under your buttons. You will trigger a JUMP action only when this canvas is clicked. So when you click your pause button, it will stop the propagation and won't click the full screen canvas, which won't trigger the jump action.

**EDIT2**

Try changing the lines (in the Update function) :

```
if (!jump)
            // Read the jump input in Update so button presses aren't missed.
             jump = Input.GetButton("Fire1");
```

for :

```
if (!jump && !paused)
                // Read the jump input in Update so button presses aren't missed.
                 jump = Input.GetButton("Fire1");
```

I think the button event is called before the Update, [see reference](http://docs.unity3d.com/460/Documentation/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html)

Comment: You talking about this  code '  if (!jump)
                
                jump = Input.GetButton("Fire1"); '  ?

Comment: Yes, use Input.GetButton only in the Update function

Comment: Okay, I removed code. But my problem is still remaining. When I tap button , my character jumps.

Comment: did you remove jump = !jump?

Comment: Read my edit, i'll try to find a link that explains how to do it

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be possible make sure the raycast on of pause button.

Comment: should be a comment

Answer (score 0):

I have always done it like this, essentially surround the entire fixed update (or wherever you have your game motion) with the paused-bool

```
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
if (paused != true){
        // Read the inputs.
        bool crouch = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl);
        // float h = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        // Pass all parameters to the character control script.
        character.Move(1, false, jump);
        jump = false;
}
    }
```